# are $_COOKIE[] and RewriteRule on Apache broken when used together?

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

I am having a weird bug when I set and get cookies after a url rewrite. This is the rewrite rule that I use:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ /$1/$2/ [R]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/$ /index.php?destination=$1&command=$2
```

And this is what I do to print the cookie:

```
var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

I also have a login which sets the proper cookies, and a logoff which expires the cookies.

Login:`setcookie("USERNAME", "usernamestring", time()+3600);`

Logoff:`setcookie("USERNAME", "0", time()-3600);`

When I visit www.remoteaccessnow.com, the cookies are null.
When I visit www.remoteaccessnow.com/accounts/, the cookies are not null.

This is done during the same session. The bug happens in chrome 9, firefox 3+ and IE8.

If I use no rewrite rule at all, there is no problem and the cookies are consistent throughout the "sub-urls". I do not know what is causing this problem. It seems that www.remoteaccessnow.com and www.remoteaccessnow.com/accounts/ are seen as two different domain by the "cookie processor".

I am looking for advice on how to keep the cookies consistent for all sub urls of my domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the forth parameter of cookie to `'/'` so that it can be accessible in the all directories of domain.

```
setcookie("USERNAME", "usernamestring", time()+3600,'/');
```

> If set to '/', the cookie will be
>   available within the entire domain. If
>   set to '/foo/', the cookie will only
>   be available within the /foo/
>   directory and all sub-directories such
>   as /foo/bar/ of domain. The default
>   value is the current directory that
>   the cookie is being set in.

see for more info 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php